# Populating a simple list box in PHP from PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, dropdownlistfor

I'm new to PHP; however, I know how dynamic lists usually work in other platforms.
I know how pg_query and its sibling members of that API work... sort of.

I don't have anything running, yet... just trying to get started.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given PHP script will populate an HTML ListBox using data from DB (column of a table)

```php
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'your_database_name';
$user = 'your_username';
$password = 'your_password';
$conn = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . pg_last_error());
}

// Fetch data ""ColumnOfYourChoice1" is like ID, ColumnOfYourChoice2" is like Value "from "YourTable"
$query = "SELECT "ColumnOfYourChoice1", "ColumnOfYourChoice2" FROM YourTable";
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Query failed: " . pg_last_error());
}

// Create HTML list box
echo '<select name="YourTable">';

// Populate list box with YourTable data
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ColumnOfYourChoice1 = $row['ColumnOfYourChoice1'];
    $ColumnOfYourChoice2 = $row['ColumnOfYourChoice2'];
    echo "<option Value=\"$ColumnOfYourChoice1\">$ColumnOfYourChoice2</option>";
}

echo '</select>';

// Close PostgreSQL connection
pg_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: I have ported the logic to my own simple table.  Check the line reading:

<QUOTE> echo "<option Value="$ColumnOfYourChoice1">$ColumnOfYourChoice2"; </QUOTE>

It doesn't look quite right & I'm getting an error there.  It's just an "echo" ... is it necessary?

Comment: There are three text strings on that line.  I think they get concatenated?

Comment: OK, that works; however, I need to select a value from that list and get that into a text box for further processing.  It looks like my original question was truncated.